How do I setup a local mirror with Ubuntu 24.04.1?
I would like an Ubuntu 24.04.01 repository mirroring on my local network.
I used apt-mirror command, but dists directory(repository meta info) is not mirrored correctly.

How to create a local repository using apt-mirror and mirrorkit?
